# Alarm clock in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am new to python and programming working on some beginner projects tried to build an alarm clock. So problem I am facing is i have got user input and current time available but when I am checking for them to be equal the while loop does not seems to work not sure what is wrong in my code
the code is below

```
from datetime import *
from time import *

timeNow = datetime.now()
currentDate = timeNow.strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
print(f'Current Date and Time is : {currentDate}')

userInputDate = 'None'
alarmDate = ''

while userInputDate not in ('Y','N'):
    userInputDate = input('Want to set alarm on same date?(y/n): ').upper()
    if userInputDate == 'Y':
        userInput = input('Please Enter alarm time in %H:%M : ')
        alarmDate = timeNow.strftime('%d/%m/%y')+ ' ' + userInput
        print(f'Alarm is set to : {alarmDate}')
    else:
        userInput = input('Please Enter alarm time in %d/%m/%y %H:%M : ')
        alarmDate = userInput
        print(f'Alarm is set to : {alarmDate}')


while True:
    if currentDate == alarmDate:
        print('ALARM IS RINGING')
        break
```

Thank You

Comment: You have to check the time inside the while loop. Or it will never go ahead

Comment: the `currentDate` needs to be updated with `datetime.now().strftime("...")` again in your second while loop, or it is comparing to the old date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating currentDate. So both of your parameters are static and not updating.
You need to keep it updating in the while loop.

```
while True:
     
    if datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M') == alarmDate:
        print('ALARM IS RINGING')
        break
```

Comment: I would instead suggest checking  the output of the strings he's trying to compare as obviously there is a problem there ..